# Como fechar um arquivo em Java?

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou tentando deletar um arquivo usando `File`, porém tenho o seguinte erro:

> O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.

Também tenho esse erro ao tentar renomear usando `Files`.

Como posso "fechar" um arquivo em Java e esse erro não ocorrer?

**Codigo de Leitura**

```
public static String lerPasta() throws FileNotFoundException{
        FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.getName().endsWith(".xml");
            }
        };
        File dir = new File(diretorioIn);
        String texto = null;
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length ; i++){

            texto = new Scanner(new File(files[i].toString()), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();     
            verificaTipoXML(files[i].toString());
            System.out.println("lerPasta():" + files[i].toString());
            System.out.println("verificaTipoXML():" + files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+1));
            deleta = files[i].toString();
            deleta2 = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+1);
            System.out.println(deleta2);
            nomegerado = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+4);
            System.out.println("GLOBAL:nomegerado:" + nomegerado);

         }
        return texto;
    }
```

**Codigo de retorno e exclusão**

```
public static String gerarArquivoRetorno(String string){
                File arquivo = new File(diretorioOut+nomegerado);
                try( FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo) ){
                    fw.write(string);         
                    fw.flush();
                    System.out.println("gerarArquivoRetorno():" + diretorioOut+nomegerado);
                    System.out.println("GLOBAL:deleta:" + deleta2);

                    /*
                    boolean file;
                    file = new File(deleta).delete();
                    System.out.println("gerarArquivoRetorno:file:" + file);
                    */
                   new File(deleta).renameTo(new File(deleta+".BAD"));
                    //new File(deleta).delete();

                    Path source = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(diretorioIn, deleta2);


                    try {
                         Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling(deleta+".BAD"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                /*  Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(diretorioIn, deleta2);
                    path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(diretorioIn, deleta2);
                    try {
                        Files.delete(path);
                    } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {
                        System.err.println(e);
                    }
                    */
                }catch(IOException ex){
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        return null;    
    }
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, você ta com o arquivo aberto na barra de tarefas?

Comment: Coloque seu código por favor!

Comment: Isso tá com cara de bloqueio de sistema operacional, e isso nem o java é capaz de desfazer. Você deve localizar algum programa que possa estar rodando em segundo plano com o arquivo em aberto, mas acho que isso fugiria um pouco do escopo do site.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto não, eu abri o arquivo com Java, visualizei as info, e agora preciso exclui-lo

Comment: @diegofm  não, eu abri o arquivo com Java, visualizei as info, e agora preciso exclui-lo. Por isso creio que seja o java

Comment: @ChristianFelipe ok

Comment: Veja no gerenciador de tarefas se não há processos "java.exe" em execução. Pode ser que você executou e ele não foi terminado corretamente.

Comment: @diegofm não existem. Até reiniciei a máquina

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173484/132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então você tem que fechar o Scanner para que o "Arquivo" seja liberado, desse jeito é provável que você consiga deletar seu arquivo.

```
        FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.getName().endsWith(".xml");
            }
        };
        File dir = new File(diretorioIn);
        String texto = null;
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length ; i++){

            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(files[i].toString()), "UTF-8");
            texto = s.useDelimiter("\\A").next();     
            verificaTipoXML(files[i].toString());
            System.out.println("lerPasta():" + files[i].toString());
            System.out.println("verificaTipoXML():" + files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+1));
            deleta = files[i].toString();
            deleta2 = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+1);
            System.out.println(deleta2);
            nomegerado = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+4);
            System.out.println("GLOBAL:nomegerado:" + nomegerado);
            s.close();
         }
        return texto;
```